# explain the linux regex for getting filename

Tags: regex, linux

Can any guys kindly help me explain why getting filename using this way.
for example: the file is:

```
fileName = "/Users/test/am01/output/output.log"
fileName=${fileName##*/}
```

then we got

```
fileName = output.log
```

Could you guys help me explain what does ##* means, I'm so confused on this regex expression.

Additionally, there is another example like this:

```
filename="testdata.done"
echo ${filename%.done}
then we got test data
```

What does % mean, I've never seen this regex expression.

Comment: These are not regular expressions.

Comment: Not specific to Linux either.

Comment: Can you guys explain what does that mean, why its pattern like that, how can I learn this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not reqexp, it it plain old bash magic.
This [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) says:

```
${string##substring}
```

***Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.***

The star is here a wildcard, so the `*/` means, delete the longest substring that ends with `/`.

I.e. `"/Users/test/am01/output/"` in your case.

Part b of your question:

```
${string%substring}
```

***Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.***

Answer (score 1):

This is **not regex**!

This is BASH [parameter expansion](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion). From that reference:

> There are also expansions for removing prefixes and suffixes. The form
>   ${VAR#pattern} removes any prefix from the expanded value that matches
>   the pattern. The removed prefix is the shortest matching prefix, if
>   you use double pound-signs/hash-marks the longest matching prefix is
>   removed. Similarily, the form ${VAR%pattern} removes a matching suffix
>   (single percent for the shortest suffix, double for the longest).